# How do I configure ufw to allow ssh on another port?

Tags: ssh, ufw

I'm having some difficulties at the moment with my Ubuntu SSH server. The only title I could come up with summarizing my situation was too long so here is my problem:

I recently discovered the firewall "ufw" command on Ubuntu, now I am trying to configure so that when I use putty to connection via SSH to my Ubuntu OS, that I could only use a very specific port number and not the default port "22".

For some reason, I am being refused access on my newly chosen port. Since I'm still new to Ubuntu and networking, I don't quite understand what's wrong, any advice?

Answer (score 17):

I guess you haven't allowed the SSH port in your ufw configuration.
In the case where you have not done this, the port where SSH is running is blocked by the firewall. I guess you can't have remote access to your server...

If you have (physical) access to your server you can open the SSH port using following command:

```
sudo ufw allow <port number>/tcp
```

Comment: No, I've already allowed my specific port number with the command you suggested. And I've also changed the port number in the file "/etc/ssh/ssh_config"

Comment: Nevermind, but thanks for the reply. I've gone through everything again and here are the mistakes made: 1-I should have changed the port numbers in "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" and not in "/etc/ssh/ssh_config". 2-I did not restart the ssh server(i.e. sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart)

Comment: what about ipv6?

Comment: Worth noting, for those who find this later, there are two files:
/etc/ssh/ssh_config
/etc/ssh/sshd_config

The first is for the client that connects to other computers.  You want to change the one with the sshd, that "d" means Daemon (not demon) and is a program that waits for clients to connect to your server.

Also worth noting that /etc/init.d/ssh restart actually does restart sshd, yes that's confusing.

And to make things more current, Ubuntu 18.04 uses "sudo service sshd restart" to uh... restart sshd.  (ufw still works the same, so the answer still applies).